# Proguard, library class depends on program class

Tags: android, proguard

I'm running proguard to release an Android project, there are tons of warning about library class depends on program class. However, they seems not correctly spotted. 
For example, the first one on the below list: both classes are library classes. I already specified

```
-injars  myproject/libs
```

Any tip to solve this? Thanks.

```
Warning: library class org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient depends on program class org.apache.http.HttpRequest
Warning: library class org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient depends on program class org.apache.http.HttpResponse
Warning: library class org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient depends on program class org.apache.http.HttpHost
Warning: library class org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient depends on program class org.apache.http.HttpRequest
Warning: library class org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient depends on program class org.apache.http.protocol.HttpContext
Warning: library class org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient depends on program class org.apache.http.HttpResponse
Warning: library class org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient depends on program class org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor
Warning: library class org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient depends on program class org.apache.http.ConnectionReuseStrategy
Warning: library class org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient depends on program class org.apache.http.protocol.HttpProcessor
Warning: library class org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient depends on program class org.apache.http.params.HttpParams
Warning: library class org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient depends on program class org.apache.http.HttpRequest
Warning: library class org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient depends on program class org.apache.http.params.HttpParams
Warning: library class org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient depends on program class org.apache.http.protocol.HttpContext
Warning: library class org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient depends on program class org.apache.http.HttpHost
Warning: library class org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient depends on program class org.apache.http.HttpRequest
Warning: library class org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient depends on program class org.apache.http.HttpHost
Warning: library class org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient depends on program class org.apache.http.HttpRequest
Warning: library class org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient depends on program class org.apache.http.protocol.HttpContext
Warning: library class org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient depends on program class org.apache.http.params.HttpParams
Warning: library class org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient depends on program class org.apache.http.params.HttpParams
Warning: library class org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient depends on program class org.apache.http.params.HttpParams
Warning: library class org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient depends on program class org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor
Warning: library class org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient depends on program class org.apache.http.protocol.HttpContext
Warning: library class org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient depends on program class org.apache.http.ConnectionReuseStrategy
Warning: library class org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient depends on program class org.apache.http.protocol.BasicHttpProcessor
```